# AttributeError: 'poly1d' object has no attribute 'is_commutative'

Tags: python, sympy, polynomials, symbolic-integration

I am trying to integrate the function `I`, which contains the Legendre polynomial `leg_f`:

```
import math
import numpy as np
from mpmath import *
from sympy import *
from scipy.special import legendre

n = 3

c = lambda h_c,z,R : (z**2+h_c**2)**0.5
c_supp = lambda h_c,z,R : (z**2+h_c**2)**(-n)    
x = lambda h_x,z,R : -4*R*(R-h_x)/c(h_x,z,R)**2

leg_f = lambda h_l,z,R : legendre(n-1,(1-0.5*x(h_l,z,R))/(1-x(h_l,z,R))**0.5)

f_f_symb = lambda h_v,z,R : hyper((n, 0.5), (1), (-4*R*(R-h_v)/(z**2+h_v**2)))

I = lambda h_i,z_i,R_i : c_supp(h_i,z_i,R_i)*(1-x(h_i,z_i,R_i))**(-n/2)*leg_f(h_i,z_i,R_i)

h_i,z_i,R_i = symbols('h_i z_i R_i')

int_result = integrate(I(h_i,z_i,R_i), (z_i, 0, np.inf))
```

But I get the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 99, in <module>
    int_result = integrate(I(h_i,z_i,R_i), (z_i, 0, np.inf)) 
  File "/Users/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/sympy/integrals/integrals.py", line 1276, in integrate
    integral = Integral(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/sympy/integrals/integrals.py", line 75, in __new__
    obj = AddWithLimits.__new__(cls, function, *symbols, **assumptions)
  File "/Users/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/sympy/concrete/expr_with_limits.py", line 389, in __new__
    obj.is_commutative = function.is_commutative  # limits already checked
AttributeError: 'poly1d' object has no attribute 'is_commutative'
```

What could be the problem? Is it the right way to integrate such function in sympy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some issues with your code that I can see:

1. You do not need to import `legendre` function from SciPy. SymPy has its own `legendre` function which gets imported when you write `from sympy import *`. Also, if you are interested in symbolic results you should not use SciPy or NumPy at all.
2. If you want symbolic computations you should not write decimal numbers like `0.5` in your code. Instead you should use `Rational(1,2)` which is SymPy object that represents the fraction `1/2`.
3. Instead of using NumPy's `inf` for infinity, you should use Sympy's `oo` for infinity.

The following code gets rid of the above issues and therefore the original error that you were getting.

```
from sympy import *

n = 3
c = lambda h_c,z,R : (z**2+h_c**2)**Rational(1,2)
c_supp = lambda h_c,z,R : (z**2+h_c**2)**(-n)    
x = lambda h_x,z,R : -4*R*(R-h_x)/c(h_x,z,R)**2
leg_f = lambda h_l,z,R : legendre(n-1,(1-Rational(1,2)*x(h_l,z,R))/(1-x(h_l,z,R))**Rational(1,2))
I = lambda h_i,z_i,R_i : c_supp(h_i,z_i,R_i)*(1-x(h_i,z_i,R_i))**(-n*Rational(1,2))*leg_f(h_i,z_i,R_i)

h_i,z_i,R_i = symbols('h_i z_i R_i')

int_result = integrate(I(h_i,z_i,R_i), (z_i, 0, inf))
```

Unfortunately, though SymPy cannot quickly integrate the function that you have. Your integrand looks like this

[image: Original]

After simplification it becomes a little easier on the eyes but SymPy seems to get stuck trying to evaluate this integral.

[image: Simplified]

Unless symbolic results are absolutely necessary, I would recommend numerical integration for this problem.